# C - Retrieving variable from item stored in queue

Tags: c, pointers, reference, queue, typedef

I am writing a program to store multiple `typedef` "Item" instances in a queue (using [this queue implementation](http://c-algorithms.sourceforge.net/doc/queue_8h.html)) and I am running into a problem getting the data back from the queue.

Here is the relevant code, minus the file open/close lines (the code takes an input file and stores individual values into the instance):

```
Sample file:
1 2 10 20 30
------------
/* create new item */
Item *newItem = malloc(sizeof(Item));

/* string tokenizer */
...

/* set item variables */
newItem->value1 = strtol(tokens[0], NULL, 10);  //should contain 1
newItem->value2 = strtol(tokens[1], NULL, 10);  //should contain 2
newItem->value3 = strtol(tokens[2], NULL, 10);  //should contain 10
newItem->value4 = strtol(tokens[3], NULL, 10);  //should contain 20
newItem->value5 = strtol(tokens[4], NULL, 10);  //should contain 30

/* add to item queue */
queue_push_tail(itemQueue, &newItem);

/* add second item with different values, same method as above */
...

/* check queue values */
if(!queue_is_empty(itemQueue)) {
    Item *itemHead = queue_peek_head(itemQueue);        //this should differ...
    printf("Head: %d %d\n", itemHead->value1, itemHead->value5);
    Item *itemTail = queue_peek_tail(processQueue);     //...from this
    printf("Tail: %d %d\n", itemTail->value1, itemTail->value5);
}
```

How can I then access one of these items to view a variable? I thought I could use something like `queue_peek_head(itemQueue)->value1` to see the first variable in the item (in the above example, `1` since that was stored in the first `newItem.value1` in the queue), but that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: This isn't C++. You're not getting typed pointers. Per the API you're using, a `QueueValue` (the value pushed, and the value returned via peel) is synonymous to `void *`. You're going to have to cast it back to `Item*` before dereferencing the underlying fields (and you better have a valid `Item` address when you do it).

Comment: Ah, I see. I must've gotten the syntax confused. So when I try to get the data back, I should prefix the call to `queue_peek_head` with `(Item *)`? What exactly do you mean by dereferencing the underlying fields? Sorry, I'm still grasping pointers and references.

Comment: `if (!queue_is_empty(itemQueue)) { Item *p = queue_peek_head(itemQueue); do something with p }` And this is C. Forget references. Think pointers.

Comment: Perfect, this worked! Now to tackle the other issues in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @WhozCraig said in the previous comment, queue_peek_head() is supposed to return 'void *' which you should cast to 'Item *'.

Another issue with your code - 'newItem' is an on-stack variable, you can keep in a queue only as long as you are within the call stack of the function that pushed newItem to the queue. A safer practice would be to allocate newItem before pushing to a queue and free it somewhere else when you don't need it to be queued anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm now trying to correct the second point you mentioned. When I create and queue two `Items`, it seems that getting the first item in the queue (at the head) doesn't give me the first `Item` I created. Rather, it's the second `Item`. Is this related to the issue you brought up? (EDIT: I believe I'm somehow overwriting `newItem` each time I read a new set of values. Can this be fixed using your suggestion? Is there some way of just passing a generic `Item` to the queue?)

Comment: You need to make sure that each Item in the queue has a unique address and a good and healthy life span :) . Dynamic allocation is the way to go.